# Google Maps Geocoding HTTP Service

Tags: google-maps-api-3

I have reviewed every topic that seems relevant and I believe I am having a problem because the configuration in which I am attempting to use this service is different from any of the other postings.

1. I can get acceptable Reverse GeoCode results only without a Key.
2. But acceptable is not optimal. The Guide documents filtering which would be applied on the server side to reduce the number of results I would receive to check to determine which result is 'best'.
3. I do not believe that the ability to get server-side filtering is a Premier Service; I do not have a Premier License.
4. No matter whether I use a current Browser Key or Server Key, every request will result in REQUEST_DENIED status.
5. At console.cloud.google.com/apis I have enabled "Google maps JavaScript" and just by reading all the other postings, I have added, probably unnecessarily, and with not change in the result:  "Google Place API Web Service".
6. My only remaining guess is that my request is being denied in relationship to the terminology of the service agreement requiring that this service include the display of a Google Map.  My application DOES display a Google Map, but I do not see how to let the Google Maps Server know that. May API stack is using the Javascript API with XML results requested via this URL: "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?language=en&libraries=places", and the GeoCoding requests [forward and reverse] work fine via this URL:
   http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml? but adding a key="" in order to take advantage of server-side filtering is always denied.
7. What am I missing that needs to be passed in the request in order to have my api key honored and for me to get a better result set consuming less network bandwidth?

Answer (score 0):

As you use Geocoding API you have to enable it in your project. You have to generate a Server API key and use it with your request.

The official documentation covers this subject:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/get-api-key

For Maps JavaScript API you have to use a Browser API key:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key

Comment: And, indeed, I think I am obeying both those rules, as confirmed by the fact that I am able to use both API's functionality.  Nonetheless, the part of the Geocoding API which relates to filtering will always fail with the REQUEST_DENIED status.  Can anyone suggest any debugging tool/setting that might provide a better answer as to the **reason** that Google's server decided to deny the request?

Comment: Can you share the exact HTTP request to have  a look at it?

Comment: Yes, thank you for your help.  It may or may not be important to understand the framework in which this application is developed, which is the Adobe Integrated Runtime [AIR]

Comment: The initiation of Map Services uses: '"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?language=en&libraries=places"'.  The initiation of GeoCode services uses: '"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?latlng=" +
    point.x.toString() + "," + point.y.toString());' appended with '&key=' either my Browser Key or my Server Key -- either fails with the same REQUEST_DENIED.